# How Can I Refactor Duplicate Code For Display Form Using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was using material ui for designing my form.

Its work fine but Im just wonder is there any other ways to minimal the use of codes, since I have like 800 lines of codes for the output only.

Here is the partial of my codes:

```
<GridContainer>
    // First Element
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={2}>
        <FormLabel className={classes.labelHorizontal}>User ID</FormLabel>
    </GridItem>

    <GridItem xs={12} sm={3}>
        <CustomInput
            formControlProps={{
              fullWidth: true
            }}
        />
    </GridItem>

    // Second Element
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={2}>
        <FormLabel className={classes.labelHorizontal}>Fullname</FormLabel>
    </GridItem>

    <GridItem xs={12} sm={3}>
        <CustomInput
            formControlProps={{
              fullWidth: true
            }}
        />
    </GridItem>     
</GridContainer>
```

Note: I have like 20 label for each input, and it's using the same component (some of them were not) but is it possible to reduce the usage of codes so my codes looks more clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a custom component like

```js
function MyCustomComponent({ label }) {
  <Fragment>
    <GridItem xs={12} sm={2}>
      <FormLabel className={classes.labelHorizontal}>{label}</FormLabel>
    </GridItem>

    <GridItem xs={12} sm={3}>
      <CustomInput
        formControlProps={{
          fullWidth: true,
        }}
      />
    </GridItem>
  </Fragment>;
}
```

And then use it like:

```js
<GridContainer>
  <MyCustomComponent label="User ID"/>
  <MyCustomComponent label="Full Name"/>
<GridContainer>
```